# Sign in with Google for web - checking whether a user is signed in

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

How does one check whether a user is signed in in the new API? I went through the docs at https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

After successful logon, Google issues an ID token to an endpoint chosen by you (for example, https://localhost:8080/callback). Your server-side implementation of that endpoint must then verify the validity of that token as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token). After successful validation, your server can

- create a session for the user and send a session cookie to the client (for example, using [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)) or
- send the ID token itself back to the client in a cookie.

The payload of the response that contains the session cookie/ID token cookie can contain information that the client displays after logon (for example: "Welcome back, User A"). The client thus "knows" which user is logged on.

The session cookie/ID token cookie will then be included in every subsequent request made by the client, and the server can use it to

- retrieve the session information if it is a session cookie or
- revalidate the ID token, which must be done before every request.

Note that malicious users can always manipulate the client. User A could, for example, change the information held on the client so that is displays "Welcome back, User B"). But the important point is that the server cannot be fooled, because it derives the correct user from the session or the ID token.